# Testing queueable method which relies on jobId

Tags: queueable-apex, test-automation

I've updated my code to do some logic along these lines

1. if no  job has been created, create a job using System.enqueueJob(QC) and store it's job id.
2. take a bunch of data and store it in a custom object along with the job id.
3. when the job runs it will query to get the stored data matching the job id.

When I run  my test methods however, the job id isn't getting set when I run System.enqueueJob()  (I'm checking that  using a debug  statement right after setting the job Id). When I test manually, the job id is set fine. Is this just something that cannot be done in a test method? Are there other ways to test my code?

Edit: sample code

```
if(jobId  == null){
           QueueableJob context = new QueueableJob();
           context.isSingletonLogic = true;
           jobId = System.enqueueJob(context);
           System.debug('jobID: ' + jobId);
        }
```

TestClass

```
 // Run as User
    System.runAs( user )
    {   
        Trigger_Config__c testCS = TestUtil.getCustomSetting(false,false,false);
        insert testCS;
        Account acc = TestUtil.getAccount();
    }
    System.runAs( userNoPermissions )
    {
        Test.startTest();
        QueueableJob.triggerHelper(actListTest,'Account');
        Test.stopTest();
        List<Custom_Object__c> list = new List<Custom_Object__c>([Select Id from Custom_Object__c]);
        system.assertEquals(0,list.size());
    }
```

Comment: I just wrote both a queueable and unit test for it, and I am getting a job Id both in the test and in the queueable's context variable. As such, it does appear to be working. Can you share your (not-working) code so we can try to replicate/identify your problem?

Comment: Yeah, I had to modify it to be generic instead of what we have in production since the code is owned  by my company but this is the gist of what is giving me problems.

Comment: It's not obvious to me how things are even running. Maybe it's an if-else thing in QueueableJob.triggerHelper? Maybe you're calling it wrong somehow? I realize that you can't share your IP (obviously), but we still need more code.

Comment: I know the If statement is running because the  debug statement runs, it's just  that the id is null when I run it from the test but not null when I do  it manually. The if statement is  the  first thing that runs  in  the trigger helper method.

Comment: All that happens before the testclass code I pasted is a profile gets created, a user gets created, a  permission set gets created, and an account gets created. Thank  you for helping.

Comment: "I know the If statement is running because the debug statement runs, it's just that the id is null when I run it from the test but not null when I do it manually." 1] Are you certain there is not another `System.debug('jobID: ' + jobId);` statement elsewhere in the code that is the one you are seeing when you run the test?  2] How are you running it manually, and as what user? Are the Profiles/Roles/Permission Sets the same between your manual run and the test run?

Comment: Yeah, double checked before posting here, there is something very strange going on where the job id gets assigned after the debug statement. Not sure why but thanks everyone for confirming that it's not a problem with the test class.

Comment: running it as a user with permissions when I test manually.

Comment: Today I basically wrote a separate class that was identical to the one giving me problems and created a testclass to test them. I used a diffing tool to ensure both classes were exactly the same except for the class name. When I test them, one can set the job id but the other can not. I made sure both were in all permission sets and that I was in one of those permission sets before I ran it. Could there be any other settings around those classes that could cause this?

Comment: I think  it's related to this known issue unfortunately https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p300000008XJvAAM&title=system-enqueuejob-returns-null-in-apex-tests